# What settings does Firefox Safe mode changes, besides disabling themes, extensions or add ons?

Tags: firefox, angular-material2, ngx-datatable

There is an unusual behavior when using the scroll bar from Angular Material `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` using Firefox 88+ (Linux, Windows), Chrome works fine. The scrollbar jumps, remaining on top / bottom of the cursor, or it just doesn't move at all. It can be reproduced by opening Material [page](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/examples) in FF. Interestingly, only the last one works fine (Virtual scroll with no template caching). The same behavior was observed in other library, ngx-datatable.

While debugging, I noticed that when using FF safe mode the error goes away. I tried manually disabling all extensions, add-ons, plugins, themes, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue, but it looks like something with hardware acceleration.

In addition to disabling add-ons (extensions and themes) and turning off hardware acceleration, Firefox Troubleshoot Mode disables Enhanced Tracking Protection and Safe Browsing features. Firefox Troubleshoot Mode also disables the JavaScript Just-in-time (JIT) compiler and ignores the optional userContent.css and userChrome.css files (if present). The xulstore.json file, which saves customizations to window sizes, toolbar settings and controls, is also ignored; however, any changes stored in modified preferences remain in effect.